# TCL Variable Access Statistics

Tags: scope, tcl

What I want to do seems simple, but I don't know if the TCL interpreter has this functionality.

I have a tcl script that will have thousands of variables defined prior to running within its scope -- this is done by a pre-script that simply does a "global" on the thousands of variables to bring it into this current scope.

Is there an easy way to determine **which** of those thousands of variables were actually used during that script?

For instance, if the script has variables

a,b,c,d,e,

but only variable e was accessed (whether modified or just used), I would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tcl's `trace` capability to keep track of variable access.

Something like:

```
# at the end of the pre-script:

array set var_stats {}

proc track_var {varname n1 n2 op} {
    global var_stats
    incr var_stats($varname.$op)
}

foreach var $list_of_varnames {
    foreach op {array read write unset} {
        set var_stats($var.$op) 0
        trace add variable $var $op [list track_var $var]
    }
}
```

The code above will increment the appropriate stats (array, read, write and unset) for the variables when they are accessed. At the end of the script just dump the array with either an `array get` or a `parray`.

---

### Updated answer:

I just reread your question and realize that if you just want to know which variable is accessed then there is a simpler way to do it:

```
array set var_stats {}

proc track_var {varname n1 n2 op} {
    global var_stats
    set var_stats($varname) 1
}

foreach var $list_of_varnames {
    trace add variable $var {array read write unset} [list track_var $var]
}
```

Then at the end of the script just do an `array names` to get a list of all variables accessed.

Comment: use `trace add variable $var {array read write unset} track_var`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thanks, didn't know it could do that. Updated my answer.

Comment: You should probably add the name of the variable to the callback, otherwise this will give you something strange: `upvar #0 foo bar; set bar baz` will tell the variable `bar` has been edited, not `foo`.

Comment: better late than never. thanks so much guys, that worked flawlessly!

Comment: @user2356553: If this solves your problem then please accept the answer. More than just gaining points for myself it tells the system than it is the answer you're looking for. This prevents the question from being flagged for deletion and gives the question a greater chance to be linked with a future duplicate question.